# Google native ad click not working in android

Tags: android, admob

I am using google native ad GoogleNativeAdsAddon-1.0.0.jar , native ad showing properly but click event on image and text not working. means it is not redirecting on any webpage . i also debug the code and find `contentAd.performClick(NativeContentAd.ASSET_HEADLINE);` 
for headline not redirecting on any page . for testing i am using test id of native ad

Answer (score 0):

The add-on jar for Google's native ad architecture is no longer necessary, and no longer works. Just use the latest version of the SDK (8.4.0 at the moment). It has all the resources necessary to show native ads from AdMob and DFP.